# "Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected" when using Webpack Shell Plugin

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm using [Webpack Shell Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-shell-plugin) to run scripts after the Webpack build completes.

However, when I run Webpack I get these warnings:

```
(node:91967) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 unpipe listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:91967) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:91967) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:91967) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
Running onBuildExit
```

This is my plugin configuration:

```
config.plugins.push(new WebpackShellPlugin({
    onBuildExit: [
        "echo 'Running onBuildExit'",
        "cp file1.js dist/file1.js",
        "cp file2.js dist/file2.js",
        "cp file3.js dist/file3.js",
        "cp file4.js dist/file4.js",
        "cp file5.js dist/file5.js",
    ]
}))
```

What is the cause of these warnings and how can I fix them?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't address the root cause, but the solution for me was to merge the individual commands into one longer script.

```
config.plugins.push(new WebpackShellPlugin({
    onBuildExit: [
        `
        echo 'Running onBuildExit'
        cp file1.js dist/file1.js
        cp file2.js dist/file2.js
        cp file3.js dist/file3.js
        cp file4.js dist/file4.js
        cp file5.js dist/file5.js
        `
    ]
}))
```